# How can i get my table to populate using a trigger function?

Tags: postgresql

i have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_student()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE')
THEN
INSERT INTO cancel(eno, excode,sno,cdate,cuser)
VALUES ((SELECT entry.eno FROM entry
     JOIN student ON (entry.sno = student.sno)
     WHERE entry.sno = OLD.sno),(SELECT entry.excode FROM entry
     JOIN student ON (entry.sno = student.sno)
     WHERE entry.sno = OLD.sno),
     OLD.sno,current_timestamp,current_user);
END IF;
RETURN OLD;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and i also have the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_student
BEFORE DELETE
on student
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_student();
```

the idea is when i delete a student from the student relation then the entry in the entry relation also delete and my cancel relation updates.

this is what i put into my student relation:

```
INSERT INTO 
student(sno, sname, semail) VALUES (1, 'a. adedeji', 'ayooladedeji@live.com');
```

and this is what i put into my entry relation:

```
INSERT INTO
entry(excode, sno, egrade) VALUES (1, 1, 98.56);
```

when i execute the command

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE sno = 1;
```

it deletes the student and also the corresponding entry and the query returns with no errors however when i run a select on my cancel table the table shows up empty?

Comment: Can you not use a 'cascade' drop constraint? Triggers seem like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show how the corresponding `entry` is deleted. If the entry is deleted before the `student` record then that causes the problem because then the `INSERT` in the trigger will fail because the `SELECT` statement will not provide any values to insert. Is the corresponding `entry` deleted through a CASCADING delete on `student`?

Also, your trigger can be much simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_student() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cancel(eno, excode, sno, cdate, cuser)
    VALUES (SELECT eno, excode, sno, current_timestamp, current_user
            FROM entry
            WHERE sno = OLD.sno);
    RETURN OLD;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

First of all, the function only fires on a `DELETE` trigger, so you do not have to test for `TG_OP`. Secondly, in the `INSERT` statement you never access any data from the `student` relation so there is no need to `JOIN` to that relation; the `sno` does come from the student relation, but through the `OLD` implicit parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your DB schema and it's not very clear what your problem is, but it looks like a cascade delete is interfering somewhere. Specifically:

1. Before deleting the `student`, you insert something into `cancel` that references it.
2. Postgres proceeds to delete the row in `student`.
3. Postgres proceeds to honors all applicable cascade deletes.
4. Postgres deletes rows in `entry` and ... `cancel` (including the one you just inserted).

A few remarks:

Firstly, and as a rule of thumb, `before` triggers should never have side-effects on anything but the row itself. Inserting row in a `before delete` trigger is a big no no: besides introducing potential problems related such as Postgres reporting an incorrect FOUND value or incorrect row counts upon completing the query, consider the case where a separate `before` trigger cancels the delete altogether by returning `NULL`. As such, your trigger function should be running on an `after` trigger -- only at that point can you be sure that the row is indeed deleted.

Secondly, you don't need these inefficient, redundant, and ugly-as-sin sub-select statements. Use the `insert ... select ...` variety of inserts instead:

```
INSERT INTO cancel(eno, excode,sno,cdate,cuser)
SELECT entry.eno entry.excode, OLD.sno, current_timestamp, current_user
FROM entry
WHERE entry.sno = OLD.sno;
```

Thirdly, your trigger should probably be running on the entry table, like so:

```
INSERT INTO cancel(eno, excode,sno,cdate,cuser)
SELECT OLD.eno OLD.excode, OLD.sno, current_timestamp, current_user;
```

Lastly, there might be a few problems in your schema. If there is a unique row in `entry` for each row in `student`, and you need information in `entry` to make your trigger work in order to fill in `cancel`, it probably means the two tables (`student` and `entry`) ought to be merged. Whether you merge them or not, you might also need to remove (or manually manage) some cascade deletes where applicable, in order to enforce the business logic in the order you need it to run.